# Access NgForOf Local Variable from Component

Tags: angular

I've got a component template that uses `*ngFor` and a pipe to create a list, and then filter that list:

```
<ng-template *ngFor="let item of list | filterPipe:'filter text' as filteredList;">
    ... content
</ng-template>
```

I need to be able to pass the filtered values of that list back up through my component to a parent component - I need to access `filteredList`.

How can I access this variable from the component's class?

Comment: Why don't you call the filter from the component itself and bind the filtered data directly to the `ngFor`?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it's better to do the filtering part inside the component ts file and display it on the component.

Later, you can pass the filtered result to the parent component through event emitter using **`output`**.